# Display only HTML links jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a url and I want to display only the html links or URLs using jQuery.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: perhaps a example of wht u r trying to solve will be of great help...

Comment: @deostroll I have a html file, and I want to get all .html links to create a bookmark

Answer (score 3):

Taking a wild, wild stab in the dark here, hopefully hitting something that comes close to what you're really asking. This selector will get all links on the page that end with '.html':

```
$('a[href$=.html]').each(function () {
    alert(this);
    // do whatever you want to do with 'this'
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @Jean It *does* work. If it doesn't work for *you*, you may consider clarifying *what* doesn't work or add more background info on what your situation is and what the end goal is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

do the pattern match for url , whether the url is ending .html extenstion .

preg_match ( '/.html$/',$url ,$val );

Comment: @Jean, please give more info on what you want to do, 'cause I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @natrium I have a html file, and I want to get all .html links to create a bookmark